# Querying using class in Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, intellij-idea

i'm trying to do this query

`List<Product> findProductByCategory_CategoryNameAndPriceBetween(String category, double min, double max);`

but the return of the query is an empty list. What am I doing wrong? I also tried without the underscore between Category and Category Name. This are the class category and product:

```
@Entity
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String categoryName;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Product> products;

...
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PRODUCT")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="PRICE")
    private Double price;

    @Column(name="BRAND")
    private String brand;

    @Column(name="MODEL")
    private String model;

    //@Lob
    @Column(name="DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "IMAGE_URL")
    private String imageUrl;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private Category category;
```

And this is how I have implemented the repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ProductDao extends JpaRepository<Product,Long> {
...
```

Comment: Please also post your JPA class!

Comment: I don't see a price anywhere. Note also that the first step is usually to [log your SQL statements](https://www.baeldung.com/sql-logging-spring-boot) to confirm that they match the logic you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the implementation below, your query is doing just fine.

Please note that I've added an alternative implementation:

```
List<Product> findByCategoryAndPriceBetween(Category category, double min, double max);
```

I suspect that when you are testing this, you are not saving any products because your code is missing cascading inside `Category` class. Hence, I've added my implementation used during tests.

Category class

```
package no.mycompany.myapp.misc;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@Entity
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String categoryName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Product class

```
package no.mycompany.myapp.misc;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;

// cannot use @Data here because of circular ref
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name="PRODUCT")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="PRICE")
    private Double price;

    @Column(name="BRAND")
    private String brand;

    @Column(name="MODEL")
    private String model;

    //@Lob
    @Column(name="DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "IMAGE_URL")
    private String imageUrl;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private Category category;
}
```

ProductDao

```
public interface ProductDao extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
    List<Product> findProductByCategory_CategoryNameAndPriceBetween(String category, double min, double max);
    List<Product> findByCategoryAndPriceBetween(Category category, double min, double max);
}
```

Let's add a couple of tests about this:

```
package no.mycompany.myapp.misc;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;

import static org.assertj.core.api.AssertionsForClassTypes.assertThat;

@DataJpaTest
public class ProductDaoTest {

    @Autowired
    ProductDao productDao;

    @Autowired
    TestEntityManager testEntityManager;

    @Test
    public void findByCategoryAndPriceBetween_singleCategoryWithSingleProductInDb_expectSingleProduct() {
        var category = createCategoryWithSingleProduct();
        testEntityManager.persist(category);
        var result = productDao.findByCategoryAndPriceBetween(category, 0.0, 2.0);
        assertThat(result.size()).isEqualTo(1);
    }

    @Test
    public void findByCategoryAndPriceBetween_singleCategoryWithSingleProductInDb_expectEmptyResult() {
        var category = createCategoryWithSingleProduct();
        testEntityManager.persist(category);
        var result = productDao.findByCategoryAndPriceBetween(category, 5.0, 6.0);
        assertThat(result.size()).isEqualTo(0);
    }

    @Test
    public void findProductByCategory_CategoryNameAndPriceBetween_singleCategoryWithSingleProductInDb_expectSingleProduct() {
        var category = createCategoryWithSingleProduct();
        testEntityManager.persist(category);
        var result = productDao.findProductByCategory_CategoryNameAndPriceBetween(category.getCategoryName(), 0.0, 2.0);
        assertThat(result.size()).isEqualTo(1);
    }

    private static Category createCategoryWithSingleProduct() {
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setPrice(1.00);

        Category category = new Category();
        category.setCategoryName("test");
        category.getProducts().add(product);
        product.setCategory(category);

        return category;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html) your method should be:

```
List<Product> findProductByCategoryNameAndPriceBetween(String category, double min, double max)
```

provided that categoryName and price are defined in Category class.

Comment: Price is inside the class Product, while categoryName is inside Category class